# How to log to a file from the Erlang shell?

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

Keep forgetting that [Logging chapter of the the Kernel User's Guide](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/logger_chapter.html) already has an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Paraphrasing the [2.9  Example: Add a handler to log info events to file](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/logger_chapter.html#example--add-a-handler-to-log-info-events-to-file) section in the Logging chapter of the Kernel User's Guide:

#### 1. Set log level (default: `notice`)

- Globally: [`logger:set_primary_config/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/logger.html#set_primary_config-2)
- For certain modules only: [`logger:set_module_level/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/logger.html#set_module_level-2)

Accepted [log levels](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/logger_chapter.html#log-level) (from least severe to most):
`debug`, `info`, `notice`, `warning`, `error`, `critical`, `alert`, `emergency`

**Note**:
The default log level in the Erlang shell is `notice`, so if you leave it as is, but set a lower level (such as `debug` or `info`) when adding a log handler in the next step, those level of logs will never get through.

**Example**:

```
logger:set_primary_config(level, debug).
```

#### 2. Configure and add log handler

Specify the [handler configuration map](http://erlang.org/doc/man/logger.html#type-handler_config), for example:

```
Config = #{config => #{file => "./sample.log"}, level => debug}.
```

And [add the handler](http://erlang.org/doc/man/logger.html#add_handler-3):

```
logger:add_handler(to_file_handler, logger_std_h, Config).
```

> <sup>[`logger_std_h`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/logger_std_h.html) is the standard handler for Logger.</sup>

#### 3. Filter out logs below a certain level on Erlang shell

Following the examples above, all levels of logs will be printed. To restore the `notice` default, but still save every level of logs in the file), use [`logger:set_handler_config/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/logger.html#set_handler_config-3).

```
logger:set_handler_config(default, level, notice).
```

---

### Work in progress: Log each process' events into their own logfile

[This module](https://github.com/access-news/phone-service/blob/4562dd4e209781f6ba91d09df0df2e77ea408d86/outbound_erl/filog.erl) documents my (partially successful) attempts; will revisit and expand on this section when time permits. My use case was that the FreeSWITCH phone server would spawn an Erlang process to handle the call, and so logging each of them into their own files made sense at the time.